# Typescript generate a new instance within child breaks with rest parameters

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to have a parent class for which children would be able to generate a new instance of the same type of the child.

Everything works fine if i specify the number of parameters:

```
abstract class AClass {

  protected sameTypeWithSingle (
    x: any
  ): this {
    const self = this as this & {
      constructor: { new (x: any) }
    }
    return new self.constructor (x)
  }

  protected sameTypeWithDouble (
    a: any, b: any
  ): this {
    const self = this as this & {
      constructor: { new (a: any, b: any) }
    }
    return new self.constructor (a, b)
  }
}
```

But if i try to any any number of parameters (and so matching any child constructor signature) it doesn't work (in comment is the typescript error:

```
abstract class AClass {

  protected sameTypeWith (
    ...args: any[]
  ): this {
    const self = this as this & {
      constructor: { new (...args: any[]) }
    }
    return new self.constructor (...args)
    // [ts] Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type
    // lacks a call or construct signature.
  }
}
```

First of i do not understand why it breaks - It works with 2 parameters but not with any?
And besides is they're a way to achieve what i want?

Thanks in advance

Seb

Comment: Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17388).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is weird.  You can see that `self.constructor` is of type `Function & (new (...args: any[]) => any)`, which presumably should be newable.  But something is happening in the compiler to prevent this, maybe some special-casing of `new (...args: any[])` that has an unintended side effect here.  If I have time I might try to track this down or file an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues), but I can't be sure about that.

EDIT: As @MattMcCutchen commented, it looks this was [filed as a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17388) a while ago.  It also looks like he [submitted a pull request to fix it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27701) (nice!), so maybe we will see this issue go away in TypeScript 3.2.

---

As for a workaround, you can achieve what you want with the following change:

```
abstract class AClass {
  protected sameTypeWith(
    ...args: any[]
  ): this {
    const self = this as this & {
      constructor: { new(arg0?: any, ...args: any[]): any } // change here
    };
    return new self.constructor(...args); // works
  }
}
```

An optional first argument of type `any` followed by a rest parameter of type `any[]` is equivalent to just a rest parameter of `any[]`, so you'd expect them to act the same, but apparently not.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Updated with link to issue